# Scrollbar for tkinter not working for a ttk notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

> I had follow the instruction from the youtube and all other website, but the scrollbar still not function as expected...the scrollbar does not appear as expected.. Can I know what is wrong with my code?

```
tabManager = ttk.Notebook(window)

#Tab1
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabManager)
tab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1,)

canvasTab1 = tkinter.Canvas(tab1,width=1920, height=1080)
canvasTab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

vbar = Scrollbar(tab1,orient=VERTICAL,command=canvasTab1.yview)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvasTab1.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvasTab1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasTab1.configure(scrollregion=canvasTab1.bbox("all")))

theRealTab1 = Frame(canvasTab1,width=1920,height=1080)
canvasTab1.create_window((0,0),window=theRealTab1,anchor=NW)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabManager)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabManager)
```

> the full code is here:
> **I use pandastable not the treeview one
> **Basically this is a sentiment analysis apps, I plan to separate into 3 tabs...But I stucked in this scrollbar problem..

```
from ast import Lambda
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pandastable import Table
from textblob import TextBlob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter
import pandas as pd
import nltk

#some basic things/imports
window = Tk() #The main window
nltk.download("stopwords")
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
wn = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer() #wn = wordnet
nltk.download('omw-1.4')

#region window size & position
window.title("Sentiment Analysis Tool")
window.geometry("1000x600")

w=800
h=400

ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w,h,x,y))
#endregion

#region TAB
tabManager = ttk.Notebook(window)

#Tab1
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabManager)
tab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1,)

canvasTab1 = tkinter.Canvas(tab1,width=1920, height=1080)
canvasTab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

vbar = Scrollbar(tab1,orient=VERTICAL,command=canvasTab1.yview)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvasTab1.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvasTab1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasTab1.configure(scrollregion=canvasTab1.bbox("all")))

theRealTab1 = Frame(canvasTab1,width=1920,height=1080)
canvasTab1.create_window((0,0),window=theRealTab1,anchor=NW)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#Tab2
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabManager)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabManager)

#Parent adding child widgets
tabManager.add(tab1, text="Data Preprocessing")
tabManager.add(tab2, text="Results")
tabManager.add(tab3, text="Details")
tabManager.grid(sticky="ew")
#endregion

#region title & labels
titleLabeltab1 = Label(theRealTab1, text="Natural Language Data Preprocessing: ",padx=5)
titleLabeltab1.grid(column=0,row=1)
titleLabeltab2 = Label(tab2, text="Results: ",padx=5)
titleLabeltab2.grid(column=0,row=1)
titleLabeltab3 = Label(tab3, text="Details: ",padx=5)
titleLabeltab3.grid(column=0,row=1)

tb1Label = Label(theRealTab1, text="Choose a file for data pre-processing: ")
tb1Label.grid(column=0,row=2,padx=0,pady=0)

TokenizedLabel = Label(theRealTab1, text="Tokenized Results: ")
SWLabel = Label(theRealTab1, text="Stop Words Removed Results:")
LemmaLabel = Label(theRealTab1, text="Lemmatization Results:")

imageData = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C://Users//USER//OneDrive//sem5//FYP - 1//PPT_FYP1//server.png").resize((50,50)))
tb1LabelImage = tkinter.Label(theRealTab1,image = imageData)
tb1LabelImage.image = imageData
tb1LabelImage.grid(row = 1,column = 1, columnspan = 7, sticky = E)
theRealTab1.grid_rowconfigure(1)
#endregion

def openExcel():
    global dfOri
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    dfOri = pd.read_csv(filePath)
    TableB4Anything = Table(datasetsOriFrame, dataframe=dfOri, width=300)
    TableB4Anything.show()
    
def TriggerLemma():
    global LemmaColumn
    LemmaColumn = SWcolumn[['text']]
    LemmaColumn['text'] = LemmaColumn['text'].map(lambda x: lemmatization(x))
    tableAfterLemma = Table(datasetsResults3, dataframe=LemmaColumn, width=300, editable=True)
    LemmaLabel.grid(column=7,row=6)
    tableAfterLemma.show()
    
def lemmatization(stopWordsOnly):
    LemmaColumn = [wn.lemmatize(word) for word in stopWordsOnly]
    return LemmaColumn
    
def TriggerStopWords():
    global SWcolumn
    SWcolumn = theColumn[['text']]
    SWcolumn['text'] = SWcolumn['text'].map(lambda x: stopWordsRemoval(x))
    tableAfterSW = Table(datasetsResults2, dataframe=SWcolumn,width=300, editable=True)
    SWLabel.grid(column=4,row=6)
    tableAfterSW.show()
    
def stopWordsRemoval(tokenizedTextOnly):
    SWcolumn = [word for word in tokenizedTextOnly if word not in stopwords]
    return SWcolumn

def TriggerTokenization():
    global theColumn
    theColumn = dfOri[['text']]
    theColumn['text'] = theColumn['text'].map(lambda x: Tokenization(str(x)))
    tableAfterToken = Table(datasetsResults, dataframe=theColumn, width=300, editable=True)
    TokenizedLabel.grid(column=0,row=6)
    tableAfterToken.show()

def Tokenization(text):
    Tweets = TextBlob(text)
    TokenizedTweets = Tweets.words
    return TokenizedTweets

#region All Buttons
buttonDir = Button(theRealTab1, wraplength = 70,text="Choose a csv or excel datasets",command=openExcel)#import datasets
buttonDir.grid(column=1,row=2)
buttonTokens = Button(theRealTab1, text="Tokenization", width=9, command=TriggerTokenization)#token
buttonTokens.grid(column=1,row=3,pady=5)
buttonSW = Button(theRealTab1, text="Stop Words Removal", width=18, command=TriggerStopWords)#stopwords
buttonSW.grid(column=4,row=3,pady=5)
buttonLemma = Button(theRealTab1, text="Lemmatization", width=12, command=TriggerLemma)#lemma
buttonLemma.grid(column=7,row=3,pady=5)
buttonFE = Button(theRealTab1, text="Features Extraction", width=12)#Feature Extraction
buttonFE.grid(column=0,row=8,pady=5)
#endregion

#region All Frames
#datasets preview frame
datasetsOriFrame = Frame(theRealTab1)
datasetsOriFrame.grid(column=0,row=5,columnspan=8,padx=1,pady=5,sticky="ew")
theRealTab1.grid_columnconfigure(0)

#datasets results frame
datasetsResults = Frame(theRealTab1)
datasetsResults.grid(column=0,columnspan=2,row=7,padx=1,pady=5)

#datasets stop words frames
datasetsResults2 = Frame(theRealTab1)
datasetsResults2.grid(column=4,row=7,padx=1,pady=5)

#datasets lemmatization frames
datasetsResults3 = Frame(theRealTab1)
datasetsResults3.grid(column=7,row=7,padx=1,pady=5)
#endregion

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't tell us exactly what goes wrong with this code, and you didn't give enough code for anyone to replicate the problem for themselves.  Don't be surprised if you receive no useful answers.

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` event on `theRealTab1` instead of `canvasTab1`.

Comment: @acw1668 have tried it but it gives me an error

Comment: @jasonharper full code provided now

Comment: Try removing those `width=1920, height=1080` from `canvasTab1 = tkinter.Canvas(...)`. The canvas is too wide that the scrollbar is pushed outside the viewable area. Also what is the error when you tried the suggestion in my last comment?

Comment: @acw1668 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\OneDrive\sem5\FYP - 1\SourceCode\fypDEMO.py", line 50, in <module>
    theRealTab1.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1665, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-yscrollcommand"

Comment: My first comment is on the binding of `<Configure>` event, but the error shows that you tried to configure `yscrollcommand` option on the frame which is not supported.

Comment: @acw1668 is it something like this?
canvasTab1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasTab1.configure(scrollregion=theRealTab1.bbox("all")))

Comment: @acw1668 i tried shrink the size for the canvasTab1, now I see my scrollbar, but the scrollbar is position below the tab now..

Comment: It is `theRealTab1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasTab1.configure(scrollregion=canvasTab1.bbox('all')))`.  For the scrollbar position, it is because the canvas is packed to default side `TOP`, it should be packed at side `LEFT`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thx! It's working now!! Thx for the help!